# How to change username password in Tests for Postman

Tags: javascript, rest, api, postman

I am trying to test some validation rules I have in place on my API. I am using postman and i am trying to write some tests in the tests section. So far I can accurately test by hand if i change the value of my basic auth and write

```
pm.test("Status code is 401", function () {
  pm.response.to.have.status(401);
});
```

Is there a way to change the username/ password through code?

Comment: use global or environment variable for username and password then you can update that value in the pre-request script

Comment: i can change a basic auth username or do i need to know the hashed version?

Answer (score 2):

In your basic auth tab, where you set your username, you just replace your username with `{{username}}` *(the environment variable you create that contains username in 'clear')*, idem for password

In your pre-request script, you can then use `pm.environment.set('username', newValue)` function to update it with the new (unhashed) value. It's like you're writing it directly in the *Auth* tab.

That should work. I don't know the chai syntax, though ...

Comment: ah i see, thank you! idem for password? how do i get around it not registering it as a password

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: @A.Joly your answer says "Idem for password".

Comment: As far as I know, you will be saving your password as a plain text in Pre-request Script and Tests tabs + Environment/Global/Collection variables. The only thing you could do is not to call variable 'password' :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way which worked for me without using a pre-request script (so less maintenance):

1. Set up environment variables for 'username' and 'password', and save
2. In the Authorization tab of the request, select Basic Auth
3. In the Username field, enter {{username}}
4. For the Password field, click "Show Password", and enter
   {{password}}

Hope this helps others :)